# Conditional formatting on excel referencing another data set

Tags: excel, date, formatting, conditional-statements, names

I have a spreadsheet with dates in column c and a list of corresponding names in column H. I want to conditionally format the sheet so that if a name appears on the same date more than once, it will alert me. For example, if I have 1st January in cells c1:c15 and the name Joe Bloggs in cells H1 & H5 I would want The two Joe Bloggs' in those cells to turn red, however, if there was also a Joe Bloggs in H17 I would *not* want that to turn red. I know I can probably do this by splitting the data into chunks and just doing duplicates for each day of the month but I would prefer for it to all be automated, so I wouldn't have to split it into chunks each month and adjust things when I have to add new data.

Answer (score 0):

You can just count how many duplicates there are (with same name and date) and see if the total is greater than 1 with Countifs:

```
=COUNTIFS(C$1:C$20,C1,H$1:H$20,H1)>1
```

Then enter this as a formula in conditional formatting.